# How to expand disk in a Ubuntu VM?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization, lvm

I have a Virtualbox VM, with Ubuntu 12 installed in a 8gb disk, with encrypted LVM.

I managed to add a 20gb disk, and now I need to expand the LVM to use those 20gb too, or just copy the entire small disk to the big one and then remove the small one.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the new disk is `/dev/sdb`, the following is the approach.  Make sure you fully understand each of these commands before doing anything:

Create a new physical volume with the disk:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb
```

Add the volume to your volume group:

```
vgextend <vg> /dev/sdb
```

Move anything from the  8GB disk to the 20GB (assuming it is `/dev/sda`)

```
pvmove /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

Remove the 8GB from the volume group:

```
vgreduce <vg> /dev/sda
```

Stop /dev/sda being a lvm physical volume:

```
pvremove /dev/sda
```

Then you can take it out of the box...

Use the `pvdisplay -m` commands to confirm what is on each disk:

```
pvdisplay -m /dev/sda
pvdisplay -m /dev/sdb
```

You want to be certain nothing is left on the disk you remove.

Comment: Should this work fine even if the partition was encrypted? I didn't have /dev/sda, I had /dev/dm-0. I used that and everything seemed to work. But then I rebooted and got locked out, couldn't go past through the 'enter passphrase:' prompt. That was without removing the old disk in virtualbox. When I removed the old disk, I just got something like 'no bootable disk found!' (also tried moving the new one to port 0). (don't worry, it was a test vm)

Comment: Ah - you mean you have LVM on top of an encrypted disk, rather than the LVM volumes encrypted?

Comment: When I was installing Ubuntu 12 I chose 'encryped LVM'